# System lockup in 11.10 afer installing nvidia-current, horrible/sluggish performance when using nvidia 173 drivers

Tags: xorg, startup, lightdm, nvidia

I've been trying to get this resolved for the last two days now; I've done a complete/clean reinstall of 11.10; I've tried reinstalling and uninstalling the nvidia drivers multiple ways (ie, using jockey, downloading from nvidia website, etc) but nothing has worked.

I get horrible performance from the 173 drivers (slow gnome-shell operation/animations, slow web browsing, file browsing, etc).
When I "Activate" the nvidia-current drivers in jockey then reboot, I get great performance and everything runs smoothly, but the system goes into complete lockup after about a minute of use. everything on the display freezes/stops responding including the mouse and keyboard.

I have a bit of terminal knowledge, so feel free to throw some code, etc, at me or tell me to retrieve/post log file outputs....

My system is a Gateway P-6860FX with a 1.8GHz Dore2Duo, 4 gigs of DDR2 RAM and a nvidia 8800M GTS (512mb version). The problem has been present both times I installed 11.10 on this machine.

I have gotten 11.10 with gnome-shell running perfectly on my desktop which has a 3.3 GHz Core2Duo, 4 gigs of RAM, and a nvidia GTX 460.

Comment: OUCH !!! What about the nouveau driver ? For the nvidia binary driver you may want to try the nvidia forums http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/forumdisplay.php?f=14 If you want to try to debug it, you can look at this page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze

Comment: Yeah, OUCH is right! I've been a huge Ubuntu fan ever since 8.10 and I've never had anything like this happen before.... >.< I've come across that troubleshooting page before, but I'll have to take a more in-depth look at it, as well as that other link you posted -- thanks!

Comment: If it is any consolation, it is probably more kernel related then "ubuntu" related, hard to know sometimes with a close binary.

Comment: And why are you even using 173? that's like a 3 year old driver... The new ones offer support for your card.

Comment: @ Uri; I'm only using 173 because the others don't work.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and for me the only way to solve it was installing Xubuntu 11.10 (with `nvidia-173`). I'm guessing that using a distro without a compositing window manager and fancy effects would be a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment, but this is just a comment:

I had similar problems with nVidia Corporation G98M [Quadro NVS 160M]:
  100% CPU when logging in, etc

Everything was fine when I was using an upgraded 10.04 LTS. First I thought this was a problem due to upgrade but a fresh install did not help.

Now I worked around via blacklisting nouveau and intel_agp. Then stopping (light)gdm and installing nvidia drivers from the website directly (yes, I also installed normal gnome desktop).

Now its a bit ugly because I need to start ubuntu everytime via 'startx' from command line after stopping gdm again, but its not that bad as hibernate works :)

Not sure how I can make it working directly after logging in via gdm.

Update: This issue seems to be solved via

```
depmod -a && update-initramfs -u
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be fixed with the latest kernel updates. I reinstalled Ubuntu, then updated and rebooted and everything is working smoothly now.